# JButton is not vissible on my frame though i did not get kind of error on my terminal

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I tried make a java application which simply add two numbers and display the sum on my frame when button is clicked.
Can anyone help me? ,to get rid out of it.
I simply implement frame by extending JFrame class and do the coding in my class default constructor.
Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class mySwing extends JFrame {
    JTextField t1;
    JTextField t2;
    mySwing(){
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter 1st No.");
        l1.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30);
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Enter 2nd No.");
        l2.setBounds(100, 100,100, 30);
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(300, 50,100, 30);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(300, 100,100, 30);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Click");
        b1.setBounds(250, 200, 50, 50);
        b1.addActionListener(new myAction());
        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(t1);
        add(t2);
        add(b1);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600,600);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    class myAction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                int b = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                int sum=a+b;
                JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Result is " +sum);
                l3.setBounds(100, 300,100, 30);
                add(l3);
            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mySwing s = new mySwing(); 
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);` is a bad idea and you would better off avoiding it

Comment: can you please suggest what should I do ?

Comment: 1) **Don't** `setLayout(null);`. **Do** `pack()`. 2) A `GridBagLayout` is a good place to start for 'rows of label / field with single button' type layouts. 3) Suggest a size for text fields by specifying the number of columns (crudely translatable into characters) they are intended to display. 4) `mySwing` should be `MySwing` to comply with common Java nomenclature. Better named `TwoNumberForm`, BTW. Give labels & fields descriptive names. E.G. `firstNumberLabel`. 5) For integer input, I (as a user or programmer) would prefer a `JSpinner`.

Comment: .. 6) `add(l3);` adding components at run-time requires special handling. Better to add the label at start-up with a `String` of about the same size as expected for the result. Something like `Result will appear here.` might suffice.

Answer (score 3):

`null` or "pixel perfect" layouts are an illusion.  There are so many factors which go into determining how best a component should be presented and so much time and effort has already gone into solving the issue, you're just going to make life way more difficult for yourself.

Instead, take the time and make the effort to better learn the layout system available in Swing, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Now, your UI could be built using multiple panels, making use of different layouts (AKA compound layout), but in this case, I'd just use a `GridBagLayout`

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            add(new JLabel("Entre 1st No."), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Entre 2nd No."), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(new JButton("Click"), gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, try and avoid extending from `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class and you're just tying yourself into a single use case corner

> But what was the actual cause of the problem!?

Okay, this is a little more complicated than it might seem.  Essentially, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, but `BorderLayout` only allows a single component to reside at each it's 5 available locations, so by default, all the components are getting added to the `CENTER` position, but only the last one will be used by `BorderLayout` (ie, your button).

You then call `setVisible` which causes the frame to perform a layout pass, but it's size is `0x0`, so your button's size is set `0x0`.  Then you set the size of the frame, causing a new paint pass and then set the layout to `null`...

So, it's complicated